# Commerce controller hook_entity_delete

Tags: commerce

The DrupalCommerceEntityController should invoke hook_entity_delete before the records in the database are deleted.

As seen in node_delete_multiple.

Comment: Also in the controller the invokes should come before the field_attach_ actions.line 93 - 95

Answer (score 0):

These comments should be filed as a code task in the Drupal Commerce issue queue: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/commerce